# The Bing Tibetan Glitch Emoji Problem

Tags: probability, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, information-theory, puzzle

Here's a very interesting mathematical statistics puzzle that I randomly stumbled into while using Bing. This turned out to be deep enough that I spent quite some time thinking how one could solve it! Even though the backstory is relatively entertaining, it seems like it is probably a very general (well-known?) statistics problem.

Pardon the length, but I thought the backstory was interesting enough to share :)

The puzzle: Bing's new AI language model has a very peculiar bug. If you send it a single emoji, from some list of unknown "glitch emojis," it will randomly respond with nonsense in Tibetan. For instance, here is its response to :

[image]

The goal is to characterize all emojis which cause this response. Since there are 3782 emojis, sending one message with each would take hours.

But here's the interesting thing. If you send Bing a message with *only* those emojis which have this "glitch" property, it will respond with Tibetan nonsense. But, if you send even one emoji that doesn't have it, it'll respond normally. Here's an example of both, where  are glitch emojis and  isn't:

[image]

So, one can "batch test" emojis and potentially reduce the number of messages needed to characterize the set. Large batches are riskier, in that if you're lucky enough to have chosen all glitch emojis, you get tons of information right away, but if not, you don't know much except that at least one emoji was not a glitch emoji.

**Question**: what is the best strategy to characterize the entire set of glitch emojis in the least amount of messages?

For simplicity's sake, here are the mathematical assumptions we can make:

1. All emojis are equally likely to be glitch emojis.
2. There is no particular pattern regarding which emojis are glitch tokens and which aren't.
3. The various emojis' glitch/not glitch statuses are all conditionally independent of one another.
4. In particular, if we know that some emoji is or is not a glitch emoji, we assume this has no bearing on the probability for, e.g. neighboring glitch emojis, or any other emoji.
5. We are given access to a black-box function that takes as input some subset set of emojis, and returns TRUE if and only if every single emoji is a glitch emoji.

Then the question, really, is: if you, as a staunch frequentist/Bayesian/whatever, were required to solve this problem and maximize your chances of doing so in as few queries as possible, in some provably optimal matter (relative to whatever you view as 'optimal') how would you go about it?

It seems likely to me that there are multiple notions of "best" here, and Bayesians and frequentists may have different views on this. One person may try to look at the expected value of the number of messages sent; another may look at the likelihood function, etc. So, I've left it open. I will post my partial solution below.

Comment: I think you need to say what you mean by "best" in the frequentist setting (I assume you mean minimum expected value for the Bayesian version, but you can't take expectations over states of nature for the frequentist version)

Comment: @ThomasLumley yes, this is a good point - part of the subtlety here is how to even formulate the entire thing in a way that is "legal" in the frequentist point of view! Still, though, it seems an interesting question which ought to have some reasonable answer - or perhaps multiple reasonable answers, which satisfy different optimality criteria that may be of interest to different statistical philosophies. I'll add a note about that.

Comment: This seems to me to be related to the "poisoned wine" problem:
Given N glasses of wine out of which M are poisoned, how many glasses do you need to test to know exactly which ones are poisoned or not. (You can mix glasses together to "batch sample"). https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639/logic-problem-identifying-poisoned-wines-out-of-a-sample-minimizing-test-subje?rq=1 . (Couldn't leave a comment because I don't have enough reputation)

Comment: Yes, very related - the poisoned wines would be the "non-glitch emojis." However, the key difference there is with that version you somehow know, in advance, exactly how many poisoned wines/non-glitch emojis there are, whereas here, you don't. If you somehow knew that all but one emoji were glitch, then you could do log(N) tests. But actually determining that to begin with is almost as hard as the original problem!

Comment: This question reads like a slight variant of standard mathematical coin-weighing puzzles.  See https://www.quantamagazine.org/seeking-mathematical-truth-in-counterfeit-coin-puzzles-20220729/ for instance.  It also has much in common with the problem of optimally conducting tests to detect a condition using compositing.  (One original application was detecting venereal diseases in the army, where a single test of a pooled blood subsample will indicate reliably whether one or more aliquots displays the disease, but of course will not tell you which aliquot it is.)

Comment: BTW, the "equally likely" assumption appears to have no foundation and might even lead to inferior solutions.

Comment: If all the emojis are not glitch, then the best strategy is to test all independently and use no batches. That's because every non-glitch needs to be tested as individual. This indicates that the best strategy will depend on the amount of non-glitch and glitch emojis.

Answer (score 8):

##### The poisoned wine problem --- combinatorial group testing

The problem stated here is not really a statistical problem --- it is primarily a combinatorial problem that is sometimes referred to as [combinatorial group testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_testing#Testing_Methods).  This problem occurs when we have a finite set of objects with some defective objects and we need to establish the identity of the defective objects through a set of pooled tests that come up positive if there is any defective object in the pool.  The problem is called "non-adaptive" if we assume that you specify all the tests before seeing any of the test results, and it is "adaptive" if you do the tests one-at-a-time and can customise each test based on previous results.  (It appears that you are interested in the latter case.)  This problem was discussed initially in [Dorfman (1943)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2235930) and it arose during World War II in relation to the problem of testing soldiers for syphilis using a limited number of pooled tests.

An important aspect of the mathematics of this problem were examined in [Frankl and Furedi (1984)](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82647029.pdf) where the authors established bounds on the number of tests required for identification of the defective objects.  In [Chang, Hwang and Weng (1989)](https://nyaspubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1749-6632.1989.tb16386.x) the authors established more specific results for problems with two or three defective objects in the set.  You can also find a broader discussion on non-adaptive combinatorial group testing in [Du and Hwang (1999)](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/4252#t=aboutBook), Ch 7-9.  The problem of forming an appropriate set of tests is a combinatorial optimisation problem.  Although there may be some small amount of statistical content involved in measuring the performance of methods under different distributions for the number of defective objects, the "meat" of the problem is purely combinatorial in nature.

This problem sometimes goes under the name of the "poisoned wine problem" where there are a set of bottles of wine and you have to identify the poisoned bottles using a limited number of tasters.  This problem is discussed in some associated Math.SE questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/639/) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/59939/).  As you will see, this is mostly a combinatorial problem with little statistical content.

##### A related statistical problem --- the pooled binomial model

Now, although there is no statistical analysis in your present problem, there is a closely related statistical problem that arises when we want to test for the presence of a rare condition in a set of objects based on binary tests using pooled sampling, in the case where each sampled item only goes in one pool.  This variant of the problem reduces the combinatorial aspect of the problem and thereby increases the relative size of the statistical content.

This problem was discussed initially in [Dorfman (1943)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2235930) and leads to a "pooled binomial model" examined in detail in [O'Neill and McLure (2020)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.04396).  The problem typically arises in situations where it is relatively easy/cheap to obtain sample items but difficult/expensive to test them for the presence of the binary outcome of interest.  As an example occurs in [Chiang and Reeves (1962)](https://doi.org/10.1093/oxfordjournals.aje.a120259), where the authors examined the use of pooled testing to test for the presence of a rare virus in mosquito populations.  The authors noted that it was impractical to test each individual mosquito caught in their sample (due to the time and effort required to complete the isolation and identification of the virus with current laboratory techniques) so they tested them in "pools" instead.  Specifically, the researchers captured multiple mosquitos, crushed groups of them into a single test tube, and then tested the resulting blood pool for the virus of interest.

In this latter problem, we have a statistical model based on a "pooled binomial distribution" which is a generalisation of the ordinary binomial distribution.  Suppose we have an infinite population of objects with some binary characteristic with unknown prevalence $0 \leqslant \theta \leqslant 1$ (and our goal is to estimate this value).  For our sampling scheme, we take $K$ pools with sizes $\tilde{\mathbf{s}} \equiv (\tilde{s}_1,...,\tilde{s}_K)$ and let $\mathbf{z} \equiv (z_1,...,z_K)$ denote the binary outcomes of the tests in these pools.  Then the sampling distribution for the outcomes is:

$$\begin{align}
\text{PoolBin}(\mathbf{z} | \tilde{\mathbf{s}}, \theta) 
&= \prod_{k=1}^K \text{Bern}(z_k|1-(1-\theta)^{\tilde{s}_k}) \\[6pt]
&= \prod_{k=1}^K (1-\theta)^{1-z_k} [1-(1-\theta)^{\tilde{s}_k}]^{z_k}. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

This distribution can also be written in alternative form by using a vector of unique pool sizes and counts of the number of sampling pools at each size.  To do this, we let $s \equiv (s_1,...,s_M)$ denote the unique pool sizes and let $\mathbf{n} \equiv (n_1,...,n_M)$ denote the corresponding number of pools of each size and $\mathbf{y} \equiv (y_1,...,y_M)$ denote the corresponding counts of positive binary outcomes for the pools of each size.  We can then write the distribution in alternative form as:

$$\begin{align}
\text{PoolBin}(\mathbf{y} | \mathbf{n}, \mathbf{s}, \theta) 
&= \prod_i \text{Bin}(y_i|n_i,1-(1-\theta)^{s_i}) \\[6pt]
&= (1-\theta)^{\sum s_i} \prod_i {n_i \choose y_i} \text{Bin}(y_i|n_i,1-(1-\theta)^{s_i})^{y_i}. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

(**Note**: The pooled binomial distribution examined in O'Neill and McLure (2020) is slightly broader than the distribution shown here; it involves an additional excess intensity parameter $\lambda$.  The distribution shown here is the special case of the pooled binomial distribution where $\lambda=0$.)

A natural question that arises in pooled sampling problems is how large a pool should be used for testing.  This can be framed as a cost-optimisation problem (e.g., by specifying separate costs for sampling and testing) or it can be examined in terms of "information" produced by sample items within pools of different sizes.  The information properties of the pooled binomial distribution are examined in [O'Neill and McLure (2020)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.04396) (see esp. pp. 9-15).  In Figure 1 (replicated below) they show the unit-information for a single unit being tested as part of a pool.  The unit-information depends on the true prevalence $\theta$ and the pool size $s$.

[image]

As can be seen from the figure, there is a loss of information from pooling, which is due to the fact that multiple units are tested in a pool and a positive outcome fails to identify which of the specific units have positive outcomes.  This loss of information is minor when the true prevalence is small but it is large when the true prevalence is larger.  If you impose assumed costs on the sampling and testing then it is possible to optimise the pool sizes by specifying this as an appropriate constrained optimisation problem that seeks to optimise the total information given a cost constraint.  If you would like to learn more about this distribution, its information properties, and the optimisation of pool sizes in pooled sampling, I recommend that you read the linked paper for more details.

Comment: You've misunderstood the question: the poisoned wine problem assumes there is exactly one non-glitch emoji, which is not the case here. But thanks!

Comment: @MikeBattaglia: Thanks for pointing that out.  I have revised the initial section to specify that your problem is a generalisation of the poisoned wine problem (rather than the classical problem) and I have revised this section to add more details about that generalisation.  I do not know the optimal algorithm in this case, but hopefully the information given here assists.

Comment: Because some of the simple, standard coin-weighing problems and compositing methods have solutions superior to the binary one, I suspect some additional assumptions are lurking behind the assertion that the binary number method is optimal.

Comment: Yes, fair enough.  I've removed the assertion of optimality.

Comment: (+1) Don't you think having "an *unknown* number of items which have the binary characteristic of interest" [my emphasis] does make it a statistical problem? If you take a random sample of $n_1$ as your first batch the no. glitch emojis in that provides a basis for inference about the number in the remaining $3782-n_1$, affecting your choice of $n_2$.

Comment: @Scortchi-ReinstateMonica I think since the OP’s stated goal is to characterize the entire set rather than estimate some parameter, compute a statistic, test a hypothesis about each sample set, etc., it isn’t statistical but rather about optimality of the process

Comment: Well yes, that is the goal, but again you seem to have misunderstood the the problem. The point that you don't know in advance what $\theta$ is: as I am sure you can imagine, Bing doesn't just tell you how many glitch emojis there are! So - given most strategies I can think of - you have to estimate it as you go along, using your estimate to guide which tests you do, and trying to balance tests to estimate $\theta$ with tests that estimate the actual set.

Comment: However, the second half of your answer seems to is very interesting, and does explain why this even just estimating $\theta$ - a sub-problem of the larger problem I have presented - is a very interesting statistical problem!

Comment: I have revised the first part of my answer on this problem.

Comment: @Ben, your latest revision has a lot of great insight, and I appreciate your efforts - while I don't want to make you revise this again and again, I'll just note for reference for others reading that there is still a misunderstanding in what the problem is. There's no restriction to predetermine all of these tests before seeing any results - you get feedback with every message to Bing, of course - and I tried to say very clearly in my message above, and my answer that the *entire point* of the question is to adapt the tests as you go and build an optimal strategy to do so.

Comment: However: I should certainly thank you for all of this information! I guess the problem I've posed is perhaps in the literature as an *adaptive* group testing problem. Unless you are claiming that somehow, magically, the optimal strategy is somehow non-adaptive and doesn't require any sort of statistical estimation or probabilistic element to it at all - which would be very surprising to me, as the way I'd solved the problem is to look for the maximum-entropy test to do at every single point.

Comment: @MikeBattaglia: No problem, thanks Mike.  I have edited again to discuss both the adaptive and non-adaptive variants.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my partial answer thus far. This kind of uses information-theoretic/Bayesian reasoning but I think you could probably reformulate it in frequentist terms.

One can think about, for instance, how much information one gets from each query, on average. This is the entropy. So, it would make sense to try to choose queries that maximize the entropy.

If the true proportion of glitch emojis is $\theta$, then the entropy from querying only one is the binary entropy function $H_b(\theta) = -\theta \log \theta - (1-\theta) \log (1-\theta)$.

Now, suppose we query $N$ emojis at once. Well, we have another Bernoulli random variable, which will be $1$ (or "glitch") iff all of them are. So, the success probability is $\theta^N$, and the entropy is simply $H_b(\theta^N)$.

Graphing all of these makes clear that the ideal batch size depends on $\theta$:

[image]

So, in general, as $\theta$ increases, it becomes more beneficial to do larger batches. For instance, if $\theta = 0.5$, you have a 50/50 chance of success, and get one bit of entropy from querying a single emoji. But if $\theta = ~0.707$, you now have a 50/50 chance of success from querying two emojis instead. And in general, whenever $\theta = 0.5^{1/N}$, a query of $N$ emojis has the same entropy as just querying one if it's $0.5$.

So, at least one partial starting point is:

1. Try to estimate $\theta$ from a small random sample (what batch size to use for *this* is another interesting question).
2. Given that, choose the batch size accordingly to maximize the entropy. This is the value such that the success of the batch is as close to a 50/50 chance of success as possible.
3. The initial query, at least, should be with that batch size.

In particular, from this we can at least see that if $\theta$ is less than about $0.62$, the entropy will be maximized for N=1 queries. So, if your estimate gives you a reasonable amount of certainty that this is true, it would seem that the optimal strategy really is just doing one emoji at a time.

If you do have $\hat \theta > 0.62$, then things seem a bit more interesting.

Your first query should then be of the ideal batch size. But from there, I'm not quite sure what is best. Whenever you get a result of "true", things are easy - you have a simpler version of the original problem with a smaller search space. But for any "false" result, you now have a complex joint dependency between the emojis. What is the best way to deal with that?

In principle, the answer seems to be to keep updating at each step and looking for whichever query maximizes the entropy, given everything you know so far. But, I'm not sure if there's a "fast" way to compute this for all $2^N$ possible queries. So one question is if there is a fast way, or if not, if there's some heuristic that's good enough.

This is my partial solution. And, for what it's worth, though I've kind of used Bayesian terms above, I don't think that I've actually used any prior probability anywhere. So, in principle it seems one ought to be able to reformulate everything in a frequentist way, if one wants.

Comment: For a definitive answer, aren't you going to need to send at least one message for every non-glitch emoji to demonstrate that it's non-glitch? Or are we just going for 'learn as much as possible' in some sense.

Comment: Yes, but it's *non-glitch* that I'm interested in.  You can't tell that a given emoji is *non-glitch* unless you send a message containing **only** that emoji and emojis (already/subsequently) known to be glitch. So if there are 2000 non-glitch emojis you need to send 2000 messages to prove that they are all non-glitch. (Or perhaps some complicated fractional factorial version of this.)

Comment: @ThomasLumley is right; consider the case with two non-glitch emojis, and think about how you would identify them.  Even if you know all the other emojis are glitch, you still don't know whether those two are, and it will take two queries to identify them both - all one query on both can tell you is that at least one of them is non-glitch, not which one.

Comment: Ah, I see what you are saying; I misread the above statement. Yes, for every **non-glitch** emoji, you will have to send one message. So there's a lower bound there.